# XSLT testing whether a following tag in a given context is the last one

Tags: xml, xslt

Maybe you can help me out: I am quite new to XSL and not a developer at all. I am sorry if it is not clear enough.

Context:
I have an XML file which I have to cut into multiple other XML files. I am using an XSL:param to define where to cut, as it is not always from the same element.

Problem:
I need to test whether an image is at the end of an xsl:result file (e.g. no other elements except a NOTES element may follow) and as there are multiple contexts, I haven't been able to do this correctly.

`<xsl:param name="resultfile" select="book/preface||book/appendix|//chapter|//part[not(chapter)]"/>`

Here's what the XML file looks like:

```
  <preface>
    <dev>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <figure><image></image></figure> <!--needs to be identified-->
  </dev>
  </preface>
  <part>
    <chapter>
      <section1>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <figure><image></image></figure>
      </section1>
      <section1>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <figure><image></image></figure> <!--needs to be identified-->
    </section1>
      <notes><p></p></notes>
    </chapter>
  </part>
  <part><dev><p></p>
    <figure><image/></figure><!--needs to be identified-->
  </dev></part>
  <appendix><dev><figure><image/></figure>
    <p></p></dev></appendix>
</book>
```

What I have been trying so far:

```
<xsl:template match="image">
 <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="parent::figure//following::p[name(parent::node())!='notes'][ancestor::node()=$resultfile] 
and not(parent::fig/following::figure[ancestor::node()=$resultfile])">
<xsl:attribute name="type">middle</xsl:attribute></xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:attribute name="type">end</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
<!--...-->
</xsl:template>
```

```
<xsl:template match="image">
   <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="parent::figure//following::p[name(parent::node())!='notes'][name(../$resultfile) ='chapter' ]
       and not(parent::fig/following::figure[name(../$resultfile) ='chapter' ])">
       <xsl:attribute name="type">middle</xsl:attribute></xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:attribute name="type">end</xsl:attribute>
     </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
   <!--...-->
 </xsl:template>
```

which don't work and I can, to a certain point, understand why it doesn't, but I cannot find a way to solve this.

I would be really glad if you could help me out!
Thanks,
Maria

***Using mostly XSLT 2 with Saxon HE and Saxon PE 9.5 but interested in other solutions as well.

Comment: So which XSLT version, which XSLT processor do you use? Identifying an `image` element as the last `descendant` of any `$resultfile` seems easy, you just need to use `is` to compare to `descendant::*[last()]` selected higher up in the context of your `$resultfile`, for instance passed down as a tunnel parameter. I have not quite understood the possible following content, the `notes` in the example has a `p` child, so the last descendant would be that `p` and not a `notes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSLT 3 you could use match on `$resultfile` and pass on `descendant::*[last()]` as a tunnel parameter, then in the template matching `image` you can compare `. is $tunnel-param` for the simple check that the `image` is the last descendant, for the more complex case with the `notes` I hope the condition below solves the problem:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="resultfile" select="book/preface|book/appendix|//chapter|//part[not(chapter)]"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="$resultfile">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()">
              <xsl:with-param name="last-desc" tunnel="yes" select="descendant::*[last()]"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="image">
      <xsl:param name="context" tunnel="yes"/>
      <xsl:param name="last-desc" tunnel="yes"/>
      <xsl:if test=". is $last-desc or $last-desc[ancestor-or-self::notes][preceding::*[1] is current()]">
          <xsl:comment>identified</xsl:comment>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:next-match/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPJ9hE4/1

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin, I wasn't familiar with tunnel parameters, very happy I got your feedback. And you are right about the following context.

Comment: The sample works perfectly but when I integrate this part of the code into my XSL stylesheet I get the following error: "Required item type of second operand od 'is' is node(), supplied value has item type xs:string. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Maria, you will need to ask a new question where you show us minimal but complete samples of XML, XSLT and exact information about the used XSLT processor to allow us to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. This stylesheet use XSLT 2.0+ grouping feature:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:variable name="last-images" as="element()*">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="/descendant::*" 
                        group-ending-with="preface|appendix|chapter|part">
     <xsl:sequence 
      select="current-group()
                [not(ancestor-or-self::notes
                    |self::preface
                    |self::appendix
                    |self::chapter
                    |self::part)]
                [last()]/self::image"/>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:variable> 

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="image">
   <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="type">
        <xsl:value-of 
            select="if ($last-images[. is current()]) then 'end' else 'middle'"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<book>
   <preface>
      <dev>
         <p/>
         <p/>
         <figure>
            <image type="end"/>
         </figure> 
         <!--needs to be identified-->
      </dev>
  </preface>
  <part>
      <chapter>
         <section1>
            <p/>
            <p/>
            <figure>
               <image type="middle"/>
            </figure>
         </section1>
         <section1>
            <p/>
            <p/>
            <p/>
            <figure>
               <image type="end"/>
            </figure> 
            <!--needs to be identified-->
         </section1>
         <notes>
            <p/>
         </notes>
      </chapter>
  </part>
  <part>
      <dev>
         <p/>
         <figure>
            <image type="end"/>
         </figure>
         <!--needs to be identified-->
      </dev>
   </part>
  <appendix>
      <dev>
         <figure>
            <image type="middle"/>
         </figure>
         <p/>
      </dev>
   </appendix>
</book>
```

**Explanation**: group all the elements in document order with each group ending in containers (`preface`, `appendix`, `chapter`, and `part` elements), then filter those conatiners and `notes` elements and their descendants. Finally, select the last in group only if it's an `image` element.

**Do note:** the explicit use of `descendant` axis, the `xsl:sequence` instruction to retain identity, the [`is`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-xquery-operators-20021115/#func-node-equal) operator.